# How to pull multiple numbers out of a string in Selenium IDE version 3.17

Tags: javascript, python

In the latest version of selenium ide, I want to extract a number from a string and print that number elsewhere. What command should I use?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run JavaScript functions inside of Selenium IDE using the `execute script` command.

If your string contains only a single number (or several numeric characters in a row), you can extract that number using JavaScript's match method with regex:

```
execute script | return ${stringWithNumber}.match(/\d+/) | extractedNumber
```

Here's an example:

[image: Selenium IDE match example]

Another option would be to use the substr method.